# Return correct value once asynchronous callback is completed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am a beginner in javascript and am still having trouble wrapping my head around passing in functions and such matters. I need to set a certain value inside a callback and then return it once that function finishes execution. However, this function never seems to execute before the return statement is reached. Here is a simplified example:

```js
function otherfunction(somefunction) {}

function foo() {
  var bar = 'random value';

  otherfunction(function() {
    bar = 'correct value';
  });
  return bar;
}

console.log(foo());
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nFyK/).

Comment: You are not calling `somefunction` inside of `otherfunction`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**; You can't.

---

When a function signature accepts a function, it *screams* that the function is asynchronous, and calls that function as a *callback* once it is finished.

In this circumstance, `otherfunction` would be the asynchronous function, and `somefunction` will be executed as the *callback* once `otherfunction` has finished executing.

Now, you cannot return the result of an asynchronous function (`otherfunction`) from a synchronous function (`foo`). Instead, you delay the execution of the code after you call `otherfunction` in `foo`, to execute in the callback ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2nFyK/2/));

```
function foo() {
  otherfunction(function() {
    var bar = 'correct value';

    console.log(bar);
  });
}
```

Now I appreciate you might want to do different things to the result of `otherfunction`; not always `console.log` it; you can fix this by modifying `foo` to *also* accept a callback;

```
function foo(callback) {
  otherfunction(function() {
    var bar = 'correct value';

    callback(bar);
  });
}
```

You'd then call it like ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2nFyK/3/));

```
foo(function (newBar) {
    console.log(newBar);
});

foo(function (newBar) {
    // do whatever with newBar
});
```

Comment: I understand better how callbacks works now. But now I need to call 'foo' in another callback which needs to return data that 'foo' returns. It'll be tricky, but I think I can figure it out with the info you gave me. Thanks!